Format object property array on single line while having array new line
I would like to enforce ruling on object property arrays like this:
{ foo: [ "foo", "foo" ] }

While still having the array outside objects like this:
[
    "foo",
    "foo",
]


I've tried using
    "object-property-newline": ["error", { "allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine": true }],
    "object-curly-newline": [ "error", "never" ],

I expected:
[
    { foo: [ "foo", "foo" ] },
    { foo: [ "foo", "foo" ] }
]

